# Why are admins censoring comments?

Tags: discussion

I've had comments of mine deleted, every single time without any warning, and without anyone saying they deleted my comment. I can't see the records of these events, but the most recent two questions this happened on are:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283984/admins-are-out-of-control
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979628/is-there-a-mongo-query-parser-around-for-javascript

There must be some policy around when comments can be deleted, and how to advise the commenter to change their behavior so that kind of action isn't necessary in the future. I have not seen any of this kind of prudence used in any way in the cases I've come across.

Has anyone else come across this kind of silent comment deletion, or other kinds of censorship abuse?

Comment: Ah the random downvote. Next downvoter, please tell me why you hate my question, ok?

Comment: *There must be some policy around when comments can be deleted* - see [A guide to moderating comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237982#237982)

Comment: Also, consider the possibility that people might downvote but not comment because in your [previous post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283984/admins-are-out-of-control) you didn't seem to take the comments very well.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks for the link. I have to say that all of the comments I've posted that have been deleted have likely been offensive to those with delicate sensibilities but do not fit the description of "offer[ing] nothing of value to either the author of the post or to future readers." Is the policy still to delete comments that have offensive words in them, even if the meaning of the comment is very relevant to the conversation?

Comment: I don't think it should matter whether a user takes good advice "well" or not. They should be offered the chance to improve themselves. Otherwise, you're basically biting newbs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WP_DNB

Comment: @BT All of us here *try* to adhere to English of highest standards (the best one can deliver). That said, you have written a mother****er good quetion with that s**tload of da*n valuable information dude. Keep on making that cool sh*t, you good ol' lad!

Comment: Well to quote from a recent comment you made *" 
Well you guys are a bunch of defensive assholes. I hope someone relevant reads this comment before its deleted. Go f**** yourselves."* is not appropriate for the site, and isn't about the question itself. Comments like those tend to be quickly removed.

Comment: My comment will live on in your quote!

Comment: But to be serious, pointing at my very worst comment, and telling me that's why all of my comments  have been deleted is a huge cop out. And by that, i mean that what you're implying is certainly false.

Comment: @BT I don't (didn't) see the removed comments to be honest, I simply at the time looked at the most recent comment and used that. I wasn't planning on picking the worst and don't mean give a false premise. Note there are a [lot of comments in the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283984/admins-are-out-of-control) usually the more irrelevant ones are picked out and removed.

Comment: I did bet this were a DV candidate. I was about to ask the same question (though I swore to not come back to this meta hell). I also call that censoring and it's just evil. Nice to see someone has the balls to leave this question (only one UV besides mine). Not going to read those "answers" after browsing the first. I'm off again. Cheers!

Answer (score 47):

Censorship abuse? Really? Let's first review your comments that were deleted.

You point to two posts in particular so I'm going to cover both of these. The [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979628/is-there-a-mongo-query-parser-around-for-javascript) on SO contains the following comments that were removed.

> [image]
>   [image]

Both of these comments were flagged as being rude or offensive. The first one was reviewed by a moderator and it was deleted for obvious reasons.  The second was [auto-removed when flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773) because you used profanity in the comment.

Now for the [second post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283984/admins-are-out-of-control), it contained the following comments:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Do I really need to explain **why** these comments were removed?  While we tend to be a bit more lenient with comments on Meta Stack Overflow, your comments were incredibly out-of-line and they were deleted after being flagged.

Mat has covered much of this in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283987/426671) but [comments can be removed at any time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments) either by a moderator or by users who flag them, that's the point of a comment. They are considered second class and are never permanent.  If you post something that is constructive in a comment and you want to keep it around, then it should be edited into the post itself.

Users are not contacted when their comments are deleted, that would be far too noisy to get that notification. However, if moderators notice a behavior in the comments that needs to be modified, then we will contact a user.

Comment: Seriously? With comments like that I think the real question that should be asked is: *Why has this user not been suspended already?*

Comment: I'm laughing on this Meta question since it was posted, and the situation actually keeps becoming funnier and funnier.

Comment: Actually I've been in the same situation seeing my comments vanish. Admittedly I have a robust nature and some of my wording might make certain people feel offended. For sure not in those cases. SO could be a paradise but censoring without notice won't help (not to say "will make people feel pissed").

Answer (score 29):

> There must be some policy around when comments can be deleted, and how to advise the commenter.

There is: comments can be deleted at any time, with no warning whatsoever. Comments aren't the artifacts we want to preserve. Questions and answers are.

The slightest rudeness, off-topicness, chattiness of a comment, or even simply its obsolescence, is sufficient to get it zapped (with no trace visible publicly).

Metas are a bit special with this, and comments threads tend to be longer and more lax in the "usefulness" requirements. But in particular rudeness is not tolerated. If things get out of hands, mods will wipe comment threads. If things get *completely* out of hands, warnings and potentially suspensions can be handed out.

Comment: In many cases, comments are very necessary to the process of coming up with good answers. Deleting people's comments is almost always going to piss them off. So I'm appalled at how blithely comment censorship is thrown around. Pissing off users is not a good way to develop a helpful community.

Comment: @BT: comments aren't usually deleted while they're still helpful (i.e. on main sites when they are actually trying to improve the quality of a Q or A). They do get deleted when they're off tone-wise. The goal of that: keep the site reasonably professional-looking, so as not to piss of users and build a helpful community.

Comment: @BT Stack Overflow is the largest single repository of programming knowledge on the internet by many measures. We're not trying to develop a helpful community; we're trying to *keep* one. Part of that is making sure that only the most relevant information remains so that people don't have to spend their time digging through a bunch of no-longer-relevant comments to reach the gold they came here for.

Comment: *and* making sure rude comments/answers/posts (and in some cases people) don't get to stick around.